# Prolog: Predicate that tells if given integer is a power of two and is usable as a generator

Tags: prolog, clpfd, instantiation-error

I would like to have a predicate `isPowTwo/1` which holds for every power of two. Here is my approach:

```
isPowTwo(N) :- N > 0, N is N /\ (-N).
```

It works good, if I give integers to it:

```
?- isPowTwo(2).
true.

?- isPowTwo(4).
true.

?- isPowTwo(6).
false.
```

But it does not work when I want it to use as a generator:

```
?- isPowTwo(N).
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

How can I write a predicate that generates powers of two, in ascending order?

Edit: It is important to use normal integers and not Peano numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Rule of thumb

> Are you reasoning over **integers**? → Use your Prolog system's **CLP(FD) constraints**.

## Example solution

```
power_of_two(N) :-
    N #> 0,
    N #= 2^_.
```

## Sample queries and answers

#### **Concrete** integers

```
?- power_of_two(2).
true.

?- power_of_two(4).
true.

?- power_of_two(6).
false.
```

#### Most general query

```
?- power_of_two(N).
N in 1..sup,
2^_G844#=N.
```

#### Enumeration

```
?- power_of_two(N), length(_, N).
N = 1 ;
N = 2 ;
N = 4 ;
N = 8 ;
N = 16 ;
N = 32 ;
etc.
```

## Conclusion

**Normal** integers, no Peano numbers, are used.

Constraints allow us to state the solution in a **pure**, general and concise way.

Comment: What is the purpose of the additional `length(_, N)` literal, or asked differently: How does it affect the enumeration?

Comment: `length(_,N)` is a **goal**. You can try it yourself, or re-read what I wrote: **Without** `length/2`, you get an answer that implicitly describes the solutions. **With** `length/2`, you obtain concrete solutions. An alternative is to use the CLP(FD) *enumeration predicates* `indomain/1` or `labeling/2`. However, they require that the domain be *finite*.

Comment: This solution, when using for enumeration, roughly **doubles** the time and the number of inferences from one value to the next. Easy to check e.g. on SWI-Prolog by using the goal `time((power_of_two(N), length(_, N)))`.

Comment: Very well, you can use the following much faster enumeration: `?- length(_, E), N #= 2^E.`

Comment: Faster for enumeration, yes, but if you try it for checking (by calling `power_of_two/1` with its argument bound), you get non-termination problems. E.g. `power_of_two(3)` or attempting an alternative solution for `power_of_two(2)`. So, where's the pure solution, for both checking and enumerating, whose computationally cost is acceptable **and** doesn't have termination problems?

Comment: @user3389669 is already extremely close to that solution (i.e., fast enumeration **and** terminating), the posted code requires only two very small changes to get there: Step one is to simply use CLP(FD) constraints (it's tough to get users to do that, I know). Step two is to turn the goals around. Then you have it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another approach which works good as generator (faster than the CLP(FD) version using `length(_, N)` as goal), does not use `clpfd`, but tends to end in an infinite-loop if used as verifier:

```
isPowTwo(1).
isPowTwo(N) :- isPowTwo(N1), N is N1 * 2.
```

See its behavior:

```
?- isPowTwo(N).
N = 1 ;
N = 2 ;
N = 4 ;
N = 8 ;
N = 16 ;
N = 32 ;
N = 64 ;
N = 128 ;
N = 256 ;
N = 512 ;
N = 1024 ;
...

?- isPowTwo(4).
true ;
... (infinite loop)

?- isPowTwo(3).
... (infinite loop)
```

Comment: It's good to know that *not* using CLP(FD) constraints makes the solution a lot worse. It's almost as if constraints are a good fit for this problem, no?

Comment: @mat Indeed – but I made the mistake (in hindsight) to ask the wrong question. What I really needed in the real world scenario was just a generator and not a verifier. I just added the approach in case someone else might have some use in it and to leave the question as asked.

Comment: Even so, people would learn *a lot* more if you change this to: `N #= N1 * 2`, i.e., use the CLP(FD) constraint `(#=)/2` instead of the low-level arithmetic. Why? Because then people can simply *swap* the two goals and *again* obtain a solution you can use as a generator *and* verifier. Please don't make others' lives harder than necessary. I know it's fashionable to use 1980-style solutions, but for how long do you want to propagate this when other ways to solve this are much more general and *also* work in your particular case? Point others to better methods that are now available!

Comment: @mat In my case it's desirable to avoid additional dependencies – so your solution might be more general, but it is *not* strictly better.

Comment: To this I can only say: The longer users still use and advocate outdated features, the slower the progress in this area will be. If you and others use more constraints, then more general features will sooner be available as built-ins in more systems. GNU-Prolog and B-Prolog are already doing this. There is no doubt that other systems will follow. You can either contribute to this progress or slow it down, but please do not at the same time slow it down and argue that you are not contributing to it because it is not progressing...

Comment: @mat Please show me where I argue that I am not contributing to it because it is not progressing. I don't even know what you mean by *it*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122684/discussion-between-user3389669-and-mat).